# Algorithm advice for motion tracking with accelerometer

Tags: java, android, signal-processing, sensors

I'm looking to detect some basic movement gestures using real-time accelerometer data (from the phone). My problem is that I need something generally "rotation invariant".

What I mean is that if user holds the phone upside down, then does a gesture, it won't be the same signal. Given a specific orientation, I know how to compare the real-time acc data to a given "template" of a gesture.

But what about for other orientations? E.g. the user holding the phone upside down (alright, this is easy as I can do the same basic comparison treating one axis as another) or harder yet, somewhere in-between?

Answer (score 1):

As soon as the acceleration values do not change (or stay within a defined range) for some time (for instance 1 sec) you could assume that the user is in a steady position and store those values. If the values go out of that range, you can subtract the previously stored values from the new ones. That is assuming that you problem is gravity, and that you mean "orientation invariant"... right?

For a very simple case, where you just need the z-axis acceleration to have a peak:

```
x_wanted = 0
y_wanted = 0
z_wanted = 10
```

Your user in a steady position, with the device tilted at 45 degrees:

```
x_rest = 0
y_rest = sin(45) g
z_rest = -cos(45) g
```

and then brings the phone towards him, i.e z-axis (phone reference) being 10:

```
x_phone = x_measured - x_rest = (0) - 0                    = 0
y_phone = y_measured - y_rest = (sin(45)*g) - sin(45)*g    = 0
x_phone = z_measured - x_rest = (-cos(45)*g + 10) - (-cos(45)*g) = 10
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your problem is a basic transformation of coordinates. The first thing I would do is blow off the Cartesian coordinates in favor of [spherical coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system). The big advantage in doing this is the spherical radius (or vector magnitude, in cartesian-speak), which will be the same regardless of the orientation of the axes. The radius is calculated

```
r = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x, 2) + Math.pow(y, 2) + Math.pow(z, 2))
```

A very simple way to normalize the two coordinate systems is to compare the radius of each as two time-series. This should at least eliminate a lot of the cruft, and might perform as well as you need in terms of motion identification.

Now if you really want to compare the motions in all directions, maybe after you've already found a candidate based on the radius time-series, look at [Euler angles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles). You'll have to do some multivariate regression, but with three channels of data, three governing equations, three unknowns (alpha, beta, and gamma), and linear algebra, you can normalize all three channels in an unknown orientation back to your template orientation, and compare each channel individually.